How I can get from the Raydium amm pool the pool Id from a specific pair Id
How to get the ammId for a specific pair ID in Raydium

Add dependency "@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2": "^0.1.23-alpha"
It is essential that you initialize raydium as null (let raydium: any = null;) for the first time.
wsol = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"
tokenAddress is the desired token address you want to get LP address
import { Raydium } from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2'

export async function getPoolId(connection: Connection, tokenAddress: string,  wallet: Keypair) {

  console.log("tokenAddress "+tokenAddress);

  let raydium: any = null;

  raydium = await Raydium.load({
    connection: connection,
    cluster: 'mainnet',
    disableFeatureCheck: true,
    disableLoadToken: true,
    blockhashCommitment: "confirmed",
  });


  const data = await raydium.api.fetchPoolByMints({
    mint1: wsol,
    mint2: tokenAddress
  })

  const pools = data.data

  for (const obj of pools) {
    if (obj.type === "Standard") {
      // getting the first AMM pool ID
      console.log(`AMM Pool ID: ${obj.id}`);
      return obj.id;
    }
  }
  
}

